# XCTest Error: Restarting after unexpected exit, crash, or test timeout in TestClass/testMethod(); summary will include totals from previous launches

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xctestcase

My XCTest Test case is failing with the following error when I try to Tap on the Menu button as the first step after application launches.

Restarting after unexpected exit, crash, or test timeout in TestClass/testMethod(); summary will include totals from previous launches.

My test case contains 32000 lines of code.

If I split my test case into 3 test cases, all 3 test cases passed. But I need my Orignal test case to be passed.

Comment: can you share your codes please ?